# modulo operations in crypto algorithms

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic

Am not a mathematician.

Every crypto specification I see uses the modulo operation. For example RSA -

If $e$ is the public key and $m$ is the plaintext with a modulus $n$ - the cipher text is $c = m^{e} \bmod n$

Why is this $\bmod\ n$ there? By definition isn't the modulo operation introduces an uncertainty? I mean  $3 \bmod 7 = 10 \bmod 7 = 3$.

Is it the idea to limit the result to a group? Why is there no uncertainty about the result?

Answer (score 6):

**Is it the idea to limit the result to a group?**

Yes. The advantage to doing so is that we have multiplicative inverses (well, for anything relatively prime to $n$) and can therefore decrypt. It also keeps ciphertexts relatively small.

**Why is there no uncertainty about the result?**

There would be, except we require require plaintexts to be smaller than the modulous (i.e., part of the group). In your example, we wouldn't allow 10 to be a plaintext, because 10 is greater than 7, the modulous.

So how do you encrypt long messages? Normally, the only thing you encrypt using RSA is a symmetric key, and then encrypt your actual message using the symmetric key. Since symmetric keys are significantly shorter than RSA moduli, this isn't an issue.

We would also like to *sign* long messages with RSA. Therefore we typically hash the message to a digest that's shorter than the modulous, and then sign the digest. This also improves performance and stops attackers from exploiting the fact that RSA encryption is a homomorphism to forge signatures.

Comment: Thanks! As a follow up -  In the wiki page for RSA in the section [Attacks against RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Attacks_against_plain_RSA) the first point says that a vulnerability exists if the cipher text is smaller than the modulus n. Why is that a vulnerability when we are trying to make everything less than modulus n?

Comment: @Seth The multiplication modulo $n$ in RSA is in the ring $Z_n$. Messages are not limited to those who have multiplicative inverses and thus are in the multiplicative group $Z_n^*$.

Comment: @user220201 The vulnerability is only a problem if the plaintext is *much* smaller than the modulus, for example if the plaintext is 128 bits long with a 2048 bits modulus. In practice, padding schèmes are used to ensure that the plaintext is only slightly smaller than the modulus.

Comment: @user220201 This is when, e.g. using $e = 3$, we have $m < n^{1/3}$, in which case $c$ is literally $m^3$ and you can just take the cube root in the integers and decrypt the ciphertext using only public information. If $m > n^{1/3}$, then we only know that $c + kn$ is a perfect cube for some integer $k$, but this $k$ becomes very, very large on average as $m$ increases (with a very complicated distribution), making it impossible to brute force it without knowing the factors of $n$ (or so we believe).